# Find an Linear Fractional Transforms that maps the upper half of a circle centered at (0,0) with radius 1 to the first quadrant.

Tags: complex-analysis, bilinear-form, mobius-transformation

Now I know LFT’s map circles and lines to circles and lines.

This is asking for a mapping that maps an open set to another open set. My intuition tells me I should find 3 points on the circle that map to either the vertical or horizontals axis.

Then I can define the origin to be mapped to the a point inside the first quadrant and hopefully through some algebra, this would give me an LFT that maps as such.

[image: the question is the second one]

Comment: Sigh... More andmore often I read questions with abbreviations in it (here: LFT). Is it so difficult to at least once write that out?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp haha thank you I changed the title

Comment: Thanks. Although I think an explanation in the text body instead in the title would have been better...